# Varying data passed into Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an list of appointments in a a foreach loop. Each appointment has a button to edit it. I wish to pass the appointment id into the modal.

I have followed line for line the bootstrap guidance but failing. My code so far is as follows.

I have a button in the foreach list the calls the modal. 
Button code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-teal " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appointmentModal" data-id="{{ $item->appointmentID }}">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{ trans('translate.edit') }} 
</button>
```

The script to call the modal as per bootstrap guidance here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target.

```
$('#appointmentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
         var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var appointment = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
         var modal = $(this)
         modal.find('.modal-title').text('New' + appointment)
         modal.find('.modal-body input[name=appointmentID]').val(appointment)
        })
```

I am expecting this inpute field to be populated.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="appointmentID" id="appointmentID">
```

The error I get is "undefined".

Comment: it is [working](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/24/), so check {{ $item->appointmentID }}

Comment: When I inspect the element for $item->appointmentID before triggering the modal it does show me the correct value.